# Python set() and __hash__ confusion

Tags: python, hash, set

One of the classes I defined is used in a `set()` to filter out equal objects. But it doesn't work as I expect it, so I obviously understand something wrong.

```
class Foo(object):

    def __hash__(self):
        return 7

x = set()
x.add(Foo())
assert len(x) == 1
x.add(Foo())
assert len(x) == 1    # AssertionError
```

I expect the set to consist of only one element, but it has two. Why is that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hash collisions are know to occur in sets (hash maps), no hash algorithm is good enough to have a unique hash for every item, or else it would take a long time to calculate. When a collision does occur, python falls back to checking the equality of the values with `__eq__` to make sure they are not the same.

```
class Foo(object):

    def __hash__(self):
        return 7
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return True

>>> x = set()
>>> x.add(Foo())
>>> assert len(x) == 1
>>> x.add(Foo())
>>> assert len(x) == 1
>>>
```

This is a reason why you see frightening runtimes over [here](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) but note that you can expect O(1) amortized membership checks in sets, even though they have O(N) worst case (everything is a hash collision). The worst case is very very very unlikely to occur due to Python's smart implementation.

Comment: So I should additionally override `__eq__` to get a set of only unique objects? (unique in my context of course)

Comment: "no hash algorithm is good enough to have a unique hash for every item, or else it would take a long time to calculate" - that's not true (e.g. python's `hash(x)` where `x` is an `int` returns `x`, so there are no collisions in the hash values), but say the hash table currently has N buckets - the hash table implementation's going to do something like `bucket = hash_value % N` to pick a bucket, and hash values of X, X + N, X + 2N etc will all collide on the same bucket.  You probably know this, but the current wording does say otherwise and may confuse readers....